# sed incremental counter without any loop program

Tags: linux, sed, awk, counter

I am trying to achieve incremental counter using `sed` i could be wrong but is it possible with `sed`?

file.txt contain following

`127.0.0.1`

I want to run sed on `file.txt` so every time it increment number with `i++` so next time if i run sed on same file result would be `127.0.0.2` so on and on.

I don't want to use any kind of while loop etc.. just use `sed` or `awk` is it possible?

Comment: I believe i have figured it out `sed 's/127.0.0.1/127.0.0.'$((i++))'/g' file.txt`

Comment: it won't work. think about `127.0.0.4556` @Satish

Comment: @kent I only need 10 counts :)

Comment: wrote that requirement in your question! if you just need 10 counts, the question could be removed. since you can manually write 10 lines, ordered ascending, every time pop one line.

Comment: @kent here i am talking about logic doesn't matter how many counts, if logic works then you can apply anywhere

Comment: @kent i guess you took your `vote` back :(

Comment: you need consider if you want your logic "work anywhere": the start number, your example is 127.0.0.1, what if `192.254.254.254`?  or you meant the start number is fixed `127.0.0.1`? and increment <10 times? then you just post your sed line as answer, and accept it.

Comment: This simply is NOT a job for sed at all. Just use awk or similar. If it's an academic question, it's just wasting everyone's time.

Comment: adapt your question with contraint or limit. Counting +1 on any IP top have a valid IP is not the same as increment max 10 time on a IP that is not a unvalid IP after last incrementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat file
127.0.0.1
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="."} {$NF=$NF+1} 1' file
127.0.0.2
```

Answer (score 2):

You might pick a language that has IP address processing module, for example:

```
$ cat file.txt
192.168.1.254
$ ruby -ripaddr -i -lne 'puts IPAddr.new($_).succ' file.txt
$ cat file.txt
192.168.1.255
$ ruby -ripaddr -i -lne 'puts IPAddr.new($_).succ' file.txt
$ cat file.txt
192.168.2.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Using gnu sed:

```
sed -i -r 's/(.*)([^.]+)$/echo \1$((\2+1))/e' file
```

Here is the test result:

```
$cat file
127.0.0.1

$ sed -i -r 's/(.*)([^.]+)$/echo \1$((\2+1))/e' file

$ cat file
127.0.0.2

$ sed -i -r 's/(.*)([^.]+)$/echo \1$((\2+1))/e' file

$ cat file
127.0.0.3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/9$/10/;t
h;y/12345678/23456789/;G;s/.*\(.\)\n\(.*\)./\2\1/'
```

limited to .1 -> .10 as define in comment